# What do commas mean in a variable declaration?

Tags: php, syntax

I've found this in `includes/parser/Parser.php` of MediaWiki PHP source:

```
public function replaceInternalLinks2( &$s ) {
    global $wgExtraInterlanguageLinkPrefixes;
    static $tc = false, $e1, $e1_img;
    //...
}
```

What is this comma delimited list? What value `$tc` receives?

Comment: `static` variables

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same as:

```
static $tc = false;
static $e1;
static $e1_img;
```

So `$tc` received `false`.